# how to use Nested Interface values in Grid

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to Access values from nested interface but I am getting null 
but other vlaues are coming only nested interface values not coming

```
import {CyAndNY} from "./CyAndNYInterface";

export interface GetTable{
  price?;
  year?;
  custID?;
  Salary?;

  currentYear: {
  currentYear: CyAndNY ;
 };
    vlaueForNy: {
    vlaueforNy: CyAndNY;
  };

}

this.cols= [
              new Column('price','Price')
              new Column('year','Year')
              new Column('custID','customer ID')
              new Column('Salary','Salary')
              new Column('CyAndNY.currentYear','Current YEar')
              new Column('CyAndNY.vlaueForNy','Next Year Value')
            ]
```

I want to display all vlaues in Grid but only Price . year , cutID and Sarly coming not nested interface variables

Answer (score 0):

You should be accessing the nested CyAndNY property inside the interface as nested properties inside an object. Your CyAndNy is nested deep inside and you seem to be accessing the properties another way around.

Try this instead:

```
currentYear. currentYear.CyAndNY
```

Comment: can you please give me example